# Printing the structure of an array without its contents?

Tags: php

I was wondering if there is a way to print just the structure of the array without the contents. I generally use print_r to examine the structure but because my array contains some binary data, I'd rather not use this.

Comment: write your own recursive function emulating print_r?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
<?php
    function print_no_contents($arr) {
        foreach ($arr as $k=>$v) {
            echo $k."=> ";
            if (is_array($v)) {
                echo "\n";
                print_no_contents($v);
            }
            else echo "[data]";
            echo "\n";
        }
    }
?>
```

*didn't test this, but should get you started.

Comment: Add a second parameter called `$count=0` to your function and call the function as `print_no_contents($v, ++$count);` And do something like `strrepeat(' ', $count)` right in front of the `echo $k.'=>'` part in order to get some nice indent :)

Answer (score 1):

couldnt you just do

```
foreach ($array as $structure=>$data){
  echo $structure."=><br />";
}
```

Comment: This works as a starter, good answer, but it would only do the top level of the array.  You'd need to do something like this to get the full structure:

`function output_array_structure($array, $type="") {
    echo "<ol>";
                  foreach ($array as $structure=>$data){
                      echo "<li $type>
                        $structure
                      </li>";

                      if(is_array($data)) {
                            output_array_structure($data, "type='a'");
                      }
                  }
              echo "</ol>";
            }`

Answer (score 1):

I like to use [xdebug's var_dump() overload](http://xdebug.org/docs/display) for all of my variable snooping.  You can provide it with an ini setting to truncate the values that are dumped out, and it provides some sane limites to begin with (though I'm not sure what it typically does with binary data).

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 0);
var_dump($your_variable);
```

You can download it from http://xdebug.org/

Answer (score 0):

here is array structure with data

```
        echo printArray($your_array);

        function printArray($a,$return=true) {
                   if(!$return)
                      echo "<pre style=\"font-size:12px;\">".print_r($a,true)."</pre>";
                   else
                       return "<pre style=\"font-size:12px;\">".print_r($a,true)."</pre>";
        }
```